# Cause of "500 No individual errors" in Google Play Store edit commit

Tags: c#, google-play, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a simple tool in C# which uses the Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3 nuget package to deploy an app to the Internal Testing track as the last step in my automated build. It worked without problems from mid-July when I wrote the tool until mid-September (last successful execution: 2018-09-17). Then I didn't touch the app for a couple of weeks; as of last Friday (2018-09-28), the tool fails with a `Google.GoogleApiException` with no inner exception, message

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
 [500]
No individual errors
```

and stack trace

```
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.<ParseResponse>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at MyProject.Tools.PlayStoreUploader.Program.Deploy(AndroidPublisherService service, String packageName, String releaseName, FileInfo apkFile, Int32 mainObbVersionCode, FileInfo patchObbFile, String releaseNotes) in C:\dev\MyProject\Tools\MyProject.Tools.PlayStoreUploader\Program.cs:line 211
   at MyProject.Tools.PlayStoreUploader.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\dev\MyProject\Tools\MyProject.Tools.PlayStoreUploader\Program.cs:line 126
```

The `Deploy` method, which essentially does all the work, is

```
    private static void Deploy(
        AndroidPublisherService service,
        string packageName,
        string releaseName,
        FileInfo apkFile,
        int mainObbVersionCode,
        FileInfo patchObbFile,
        string releaseNotes)
    {
        var edits = service.Edits;

        // Create a new edit
        string editId = edits.Insert(null /* no body */, packageName).Execute().Id;

        // Upload new apk
        int apkVersion;
        using (Stream strm = apkFile.OpenRead())
        {
            var uploadRequest = edits.Apks.Upload(packageName, editId, strm, MimeTypeApk);
            uploadRequest.Upload();
            apkVersion = uploadRequest.ResponseBody.VersionCode.Value;
        }

        // Attach an existing main obb
        edits.Expansionfiles.Update(
                new ExpansionFile { ReferencesVersion = mainObbVersionCode },
                packageName,
                editId,
                apkVersion,
                UpdateRequest.ExpansionFileTypeEnum.Main).
            Execute();

        // Attach a new patch file
        if (patchObbFile != null)
        {
            using (Stream strm = patchObbFile.OpenRead())
            {
                edits.Expansionfiles.Upload(
                        packageName,
                        editId,
                        apkVersion,
                        // This Google API is clearly auto-generated by a badly written tool, because it duplicates the enums.
                        UploadMediaUpload.ExpansionFileTypeEnum.Patch,
                        strm,
                        MimeTypeObb).
                    Upload();
            }
        }

        // Assign apk to "Internal test" track.
        var release = new TrackRelease
        {
            Name = releaseName,
            VersionCodes = new long?[] { apkVersion },
            ReleaseNotes = new List<LocalizedText> { new LocalizedText { Language = "en", Text = releaseNotes } },
            Status = TrackReleaseStatus.Completed
        };
        edits.Tracks.Update(
                new Track { Releases = new List<TrackRelease> { release } },
                packageName,
                editId,
                TrackIdentifier.Internal).
            Execute();

        // Publish
        edits.Commit(packageName, editId).Execute();
    }
```

Relevant constants are

```
        const string MimeTypeApk = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
        const string MimeTypeObb = "application/octet-stream";

        // As documented at https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/tracks
        static class TrackIdentifier
        {
            public const string Alpha = "alpha";
            public const string Beta = "beta";
            public const string Internal = "internal";
            public const string Production = "production";
        }

        // As (poorly) documented at https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/tracks#resource
        // See also https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/automating-your-app-releases-with.html
        static class TrackReleaseStatus
        {
            /// <summary>Not yet rolled out to anyone</summary>
            public const string Draft = "draft";
            /// <summary> For staged rollouts to a small percentage of users</summary>
            public const string InProgress = "inProgress";
            /// <summary> Suspends a staged rollout</summary>
            public const string Halted = "halted";
            /// <summary> Full rollout</summary>
            public const string Completed = "completed";
        }
```

The exception is thrown in the penultimate line of `Deploy`, `edits.Commit(packageName, editId).Execute();`. That rules out authentication failure as a cause, since the earlier calls succeeded. The possible failure causes listed by the documentation for [edits/commit](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/commit) are

> - You open another edit for the same app after you open this edit
> - Any other user commits an edit for the app while your edit is open
> - You or any other user makes a change to the app through the Developer Console while your edit is open

but I'm certain that none of those apply.

What else would explain why I can set up the edit, including uploading APK and OBB, but not commit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in the Play console, as demonstrated by the [500 error code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) which means "Internal Error".

When situations like this occur I would recommend contacting Play Console support to let them know of the problem. You can do this via the help menu in the Play Console, which is behind the "?" (question mark) icon.